# Progress bar in tkinter not working

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I am writing a small app to copy some files. I have made almost everything that I wanted but 3 things:

1) Progress-bar to move while the copy option is in motion. I can display it but it won't react.

I am using this to show it:

```
self.p = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='indeterminate')
self.p.grid(row=5)
```

and then to initiate it in another def which is called upon a press of the button:

```
 self.p.start()

 shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry0, self.cam0)
 shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry1, self.cam1)
 shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry2, self.cam2)

 self.p.stop()
```

Unfortunately the copying occurs but the bar doesn't move at all.

2) Second problem is connected to the information bar that I am displaying at the bottom of the app window:

```
self.status = Label(self.master, text="Waiting for process to start...", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
self.status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
```

And then when the same copying def is called at the beginning of it I have this:

```
self.status['text'] = "Files are being copyied, have patience ;)".format(self.status)
```

And the status is not changed which is weird as at the end of this def I also have same command to change the status and this one works:

```
self.status['text'] = "Files have been copyied".format(self.status)
```

3) I can't seem to attach a picture I have checked all kinds of different options and none of them seem to work, the one presented here seems like tries to display something (the window gets bigger) but the picture is not visible:

```
 self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("az.png"))
 self.panel = Label(self, image=self.img, bg="#E6E6E6")
 self.display = self.img
 self.panel.grid(row=8)
```

I am a bit unsure why it is happening like that, just in case and also for more info I am posting here the complete code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import re
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
import ntpath
import os
import shutil
import tkinter.filedialog as fdialog
from send2trash import send2trash
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

#os.system('''/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to set frontmost of process "Python" to true' ''')


# Here, we are creating our class, Window, and inheriting from the Frame
# class. Frame is a class from the tkinter module. (see Lib/tkinter/__init__)

class Window(Frame):

    # Define settings upon initialization. Here you can specify
    def __init__(self, master=None):

        # parameters that you want to send through the Frame class. 
        Frame.__init__(self, master, bg="#E6E6E6")   

        #reference to the master widget, which is the tk window                 
        self.master = master

        #with that, we want to then run init_window, which doesn't yet exist
        self.init_window() 

    def copyy(self):

        self.status['text'] = "Files are being copyied, have patience ;)".format(self.status)


        self.source_direcotry0= '/Volumes/CAM0/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry1= '/Volumes/CAM1/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry2= '/Volumes/CAM2/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry3= '/Volumes/CAM3/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry4= '/Volumes/CAM4/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry5= '/Volumes/CAM5/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry6= '/Volumes/CAM6/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry7= '/Volumes/CAM7/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry8= '/Volumes/CAM8/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry9= '/Volumes/CAM9/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry10= '/Volumes/CAM10/DCIM/100HDDVR'
        self.source_direcotry11= '/Volumes/CAM11/DCIM/100HDDVR'

        self.path0="recording/CAM0"
        self.path1="recording/CAM1"
        self.path2="recording/CAM2"
        self.path3="recording/CAM3"
        self.path4="recording/CAM4"
        self.path5="recording/CAM5"
        self.path6="recording/CAM6"
        self.path7="recording/CAM7"
        self.path8="recording/CAM8"
        self.path9="recording/CAM9"
        self.path10="recording/CAM10"
        self.path11="recording/CAM11"

        self.cam0=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path0)
        self.cam1=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path1)
        self.cam2=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path2)
        self.cam3=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path3)
        self.cam4=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path4)
        self.cam5=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path5)
        self.cam6=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path6)
        self.cam7=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path7)
        self.cam8=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path8)
        self.cam9=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path9)
        self.cam10=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path10)
        self.cam11=os.path.join(self.Destination.get(), self.path11)

        self.p.start()

        shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry0, self.cam0)
        shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry1, self.cam1)
        shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry2, self.cam2)
        # shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry3, self.cam3)
        # shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry4, self.cam4)
        # shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry5, self.cam5)
        # shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry6, self.cam6)
        # shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry7, self.cam7)
        # shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry8, self.cam8)
        # shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry9, self.cam9)
        # shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry10, self.cam10)
        # shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry11, self.cam11)

        self.p.stop()

        self.status['text'] = "Files have been copyied".format(self.status)

    def deletee(self):
        send2trash('/Volumes/CAM0/DCIM')
        send2trash('/Volumes/CAM1/DCIM')
        send2trash('/Volumes/CAM2/DCIM')
        # send2trash('/Volumes/CAM3/DCIM')
        # send2trash('/Volumes/CAM4/DCIM')
        # send2trash('/Volumes/CAM5/DCIM')
        # send2trash('/Volumes/CAM6/DCIM')
        # send2trash('/Volumes/CAM7/DCIM')
        # send2trash('/Volumes/CAM8/DCIM')
        # send2trash('/Volumes/CAM9/DCIM')
        # send2trash('/Volumes/CAM10/DCIM')
        # send2trash('/Volumes/CAM11/DCIM')

        self.status['text'] = "Files have been moved to trash".format(self.status)


    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

    def about_popup(self):
        messagebox.showinfo("About", "This is software used to copy or delete files in bulk from the Absolute Zero VR camera")


    #Creation of init_window
    def init_window(self):

        self.Source=StringVar()
        self.Destination=StringVar()


        # changing the title of our master widget      
        self.master.title("AZ Data Extractor")

        # allowing the widget to take the full space of the root window
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        #Creating the menu
        self.menubar = Menu(self.master)

        #Creating submenues
        self.filemenu = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.filemenu)

        self.helpmenu = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.helpmenu.add_command(label="About", command=self.about_popup)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=self.helpmenu)

        #Displaying the menu
        root.config(menu=self.menubar)

        #Creating the  intro label
        l_instruction = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=TOP, text="Choose the destination for the copied files \n and press 'Go!' to start copyting", bg="#E6E6E6")
        l_instruction.grid(columnspan=2, ipady=10)

        l_instruction = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=TOP, text="Press 'Delete' to move all files \n from the camera to the trash", bg="#E6E6E6")
        l_instruction.grid(row=6, columnspan=2, ipady=10)

        # ttk.Style().configure('green/black.TButton', foreground='green', background='black')
        #Creating the button
        MyDestination=Entry(self, textvariable=self.Destination, bg="#E6E6E6")
        MyDestination.grid(row=2, columnspan=2, ipady=10)
        uploadButton = Button(self, text="Choose destination folder",command=lambda:self.Destination.set(fdialog.askdirectory()))
        uploadButton.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, ipady=10)
        goButton = Button(self, text="Go!",command=self.copyy)
        goButton.grid(row=4, columnspan=2, ipady=10)
        delButton = Button(self, text="Delete",command=self.deletee)
        delButton.grid(row=7, columnspan=2, ipady=10)

        self.p = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='indeterminate')
        self.p.grid(row=5)

        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("az.png"))
        self.panel = Label(self, image=self.img, bg="#E6E6E6")
        self.display = self.img
        self.panel.grid(row=8)


        #resizing configuration
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(2,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(3,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(4,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(5,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(6,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(7,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(8,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(9,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(10,weight=1)

        #status Bar
        self.status = Label(self.master, text="Waiting for process to start...", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
        self.status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)


# root window created. Here, that would be the only window, but you can later have windows within windows.
root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False,height=False);
# root.configure(background='black');
# fm = Frame(root, width=300, height=200, bg="blue")
# fm.pack(side=TOP, expand=NO, fill=NONE)  
#root.geometry("230x340")



#creation of an instance
app = Window(root)

#mainloop 
root.mainloop()
```

Edit:
Just as and additional problem that came up in the mean time I can't seem to change background colour of the buttons and the frames around entry field. I read up it could be because using MacOS platform, could that be? Any workarounds?

Comment: Edit2: I have find a way to make a picture work and buttons background with that:

Picture:

    render = PhotoImage(file="az.gif")
    img = Label(self, image=render, bg="#E6E6E6")
    img.image = render
    img.grid(row=8)

and buttons by adding "highlightbackground":

    goButton = Button(self,      text="Go!",command=self.copyy,highlightbackground="#E6E6E6")

But I still can't figure out this progress bar, no tips at all?

Comment: You should try starting the copy function on a new thread after calling `self.p.start()`. The copying might be blocking the UI thread animating the progress bar.

Comment: I have tried with threading but I can't make it work, even the files are not being copied when I use thread. Probably I implemented it wrong, but I couldn't find a way how to do it properly. `self.p.start()
        root.update_idletasks()
        
        for x in range(12):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.copyy2)
            t.deamon = True
            t.start()

        self.p.stop()`
And then all the `shutil.copytree(self.source_direcotry0, self.cam0)` have been moved to the new `def` called `copyy2`.

Answer (score 4):

I compacted the loading bar I got working in an older project of mine. The only way I had figured it out was to call the progress bar handling calls in a new thread and call the work-intensive functions from this thread into another new thread.

It is bad practice to have a separate threads handling UI elements other than the UI thread, including starting and stopping a progress bar; however it does work and I've been using this project to do pretty heavy processing with zero issues for months now.

Here the progress bar is working in a small script, using Python 3.5.2 on W10 64-Bit

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import threading
import time

class Main_Frame(object):
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        # save root reference
        self.top = top
        # set title bar
        self.top.title("Loading bar example")

        # start button calls the "initialization" function bar_init, you can pass a variable in here if desired
        self.start_button = ttk.Button(top, text='Start bar', command=lambda: self.bar_init(2500))
        self.start_button.pack()

        # the progress bar will be referenced in the "bar handling" and "work" threads
        self.load_bar = ttk.Progressbar(top)
        self.load_bar.pack()

        # run mainloop
        self.top.mainloop()

    def bar_init(self, var):
        # first layer of isolation, note var being passed along to the self.start_bar function
        # target is the function being started on a new thread, so the "bar handler" thread
        self.start_bar_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.start_bar, args=(var,))
        # start the bar handling thread
        self.start_bar_thread.start()

    def start_bar(self, var):
        # the load_bar needs to be configured for indeterminate amount of bouncing
        self.load_bar.config(mode='indeterminate', maximum=100, value=0)
        # 8 here is for speed of bounce
        self.load_bar.start(8)
        # start the work-intensive thread, again a var can be passed in here too if desired
        self.work_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.work_task, args=(var,))
        self.work_thread.start()
        # close the work thread
        self.work_thread.join()
        # stop the indeterminate bouncing
        self.load_bar.stop()
        # reconfigure the bar so it appears reset
        self.load_bar.config(value=0, maximum=0)

    def work_task(self, wait_time):
        for x in range(wait_time):
           time.sleep(0.001)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create root window
    root = Tk()
    # call Main_Frame class with reference to root as top
    Main_Frame(top=root)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help it will take some time for me to digest it and try it, but if in doubt again, I will return. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, if you have any more questions feel free to comment and I'll try to help out as much as I can! :)